# Why my Visual Studio Code lacks HTML

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

My enviroment:
windows10
vscode1.19.3

I use vscode to edit .html file.
[image]

It use "Django Template" not "HTML", so I could not use tools for html.
So I select the language for .html . However , I could not found HTML.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Delete `.vscode` dictionary in my home dictionary. Then I open `vscode` and found it's ok.